# Additional arguments for React event handlers (using functional components)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I want to pass an additional argument to `onChange` (event handler) of an `<input>` tag, apart from the `event` object. How do I do that?

Suppose, I have such a function

```
const f = (event, i) => { //stuff }
```

Can I do this? (I know it doesn't work)

```
<input onChange=f(1) />
```

Assuming, the `event` object gets passed in as the first argument automatically?

**Note** - I am using **functional components**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass an argument to onChange handler of  tag, you can do the following:

```
<input type="text" onChange={ (event)=>f(event,i) } />
```

Although event object is automatically available, you will have to pass it to the function so as to make use of it.

Comment: why didn't I think of this? ty much

Answer (score 0):

I wanted an idiomatic TypeScript solution, so, for all the awesome  *TypeScripters* out there, in the wild:
**React v18**
Declare and define a custom event handler as shown below:

```js
import type { ChangeEvent, SyntheticEvent } from "react";

type MyCustomEventHandler<E extends SyntheticEvent<any>> = {
  bivarianceHack(event: E, ...args: any): unknown;
}["bivarianceHack"];
type MyCustomChangeEventHandler<T = Element> = MyCustomEventHandler<ChangeEvent<T>>;

// Declare and define your custom function
// with as many as arguments as your desire.
const f: MyCustomChangeEventHandler = (event, i: string) => { /*stuff*/ };
```

Doing so will keep the TypeScript linter happy!

```
<input type="text" onChange={(event) => f(event, "God is a programmer!")} />
```